# jquery Selector for input value

Tags: jquery, input, jquery-selectors

i have here the code..

```
 <div>
    <input type="hidden" value="hello" />
 </div>

 <div>
    <input type="hidden" value="world" />
 </div>
```

is it possible to select the div with the value "hello" inside and change the selected div's color to red...?

```
 $("div input[value='hello']").css("background","red"); //i have this in mind
                                                        //but i think its wrong:D
```

any help please..

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You want to select the input, then take its parent `div`:

```
$("input[value='hello']").parent("div").css("background", "red");
```

Comment: @Phil: BoltClock's solution finds any `input` with the value `hello` and then selects only the parents of those that are `div` elements, and sets their background to red. `input` elements with a different value are ignored, and input elements with the value `hello` whose parents are not `div` elements also don't get updated (though a different way). It's not as efficient as it could be, though.

Comment: @vrynxzent: To get the maximum value out of any built-in selector processing the browser may have, change the first part to `$("div > input[value='hello']")`. That will weed out inputs that aren't direct children of `div` elements which BoltClock's later `.parent("div")` would do, but at a layer where it can't be optimized.

Comment: This is 100% correct answer as per the question, but may be worth noting that this will not really work for select or text input which the user can change. Pebbl's solution below solves this problem.

Comment: @Jan Zyka: Indeed, I hadn't seen pebbl's answer so thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: The question is a bit ambiguous in that it doesn't specify whether what's wanted is to target the property or the attribute.  Unless you know the difference and know that you want the attribute this solution can appear to work, but may behave in a way you don't expect, as others have noted.

Answer (score 41):

Just as a future note to those that come across this question, these answers are correct for when searching for the specific `value` as an *attribute* i.e. the one hard-coded in the HTML — completely correct as per the question asked. However, if the value of the field is changed by the user at any point the value *attribute* is not updated, only the element's value *property*. This will lead to unexpected behaviour in the form of selecting elements that actually have different current values... instead — or at least until I find a better way — I've been using the following:

```
jQuery.extend(
  jQuery.expr[':'],
  {
    /// check that a field's value property has a particular value
    'field-value': function (el, indx, args) {
      var a, v = $(el).val();
      if ( (a = args[3]) ) {
        switch ( a.charAt(0) ) {
          /// begins with
          case '^':
            return v.substring(0,a.length-1) == a.substring(1,a.length);
          break;
          /// ends with
          case '$':
            return v.substr(v.length-a.length-1,v.length) == 
              a.substring(1,a.length);
          break;
          /// contains
          case '*': return v.indexOf(a.substring(1,a.length)) != -1; break;
          /// equals
          case '=': return v == a.substring(1,a.length); break;
          /// not equals
          case '!': return v != a.substring(1,a.length); break;
          /// equals
          default: return v == a; break;
        }
      }
      else {
        return !!v;
      }
    }
  }
);
```

The above creates a new jQuery pseudo selector, which can be used like so:

```
$('input:field-value(^test)');
```

Which will select all inputs that start with the value "test", or:

```
$('input:field-value(*test)');
```

Which will select all inputs that contains "test" anywhere in it's value.

Also supported are `!` not, `$` ends with or `=` equals...

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation and solution, Just for 'validation' of your theory and a possible solution the other way around, is to add an event to (all or specific) inputs like this to force creation of the value attribute: `$(document).on("change", "input", function(){
    $(this).attr("value", $(this).val());
});`
Now the default provided selector `input[value=test]` also works as 'expected'. Nonetheless thumbs up for your explanation and solution!

Answer (score 4):

This does it:

```
$("div > input[value=hello]").parent().css("color", "red");
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ikeno6)

Or if by "color" you really meant "background color":

```
$("div > input[value=hello]").parent().css("background-color", "red");
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ikeno6/2)

Answer (score 2):

Throwing this out there for informational purposes.

In practice I'd use [@BoltClock's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) or [@T.J. Crowder's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) solutions.

```
$("div:has( > input[value='hello'] )").css("background", "red");
```

This uses the [`has-selector`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) to select `<div>` elements that have a `<input value="hello">` as a direct descendant.

The reason I'd prefer the others is because of the fairly simple valid CSS selectors they use. This is a valid alternative, but will likely perform a little slower.

Answer (score 2):

Coffee script version of @pebbl above answer.

```
##############################################################################
###
    jQuery select extend 
    @pebbl http://stackoverflow.com/a/15031698/1271868
##############################################################################
jQuery ->
  jQuery.extend(
    jQuery.expr[':'],
    # check that a field's value property has a particular value
    'field-value': (el, indx, args) ->
      v = $(el).val()
      if (a = args[3])
        switch a.charAt(0)
          # begins with
          when '^' then return v.substring(0, a.length-1) is
            a.substring(1, a.length)
          # ends with
          when '$' then return v.substr(v.length-a.length-1, v.length) is 
            a.substring(1, a.length)
          # contains
          when '*' then return v.indexOf(a.substring(1, a.length)) isnt -1 
          # equals
          when '=' then return v is a.substring(1, a.length) 
          # not equals
          when '!' then return v isnt a.substring(1, a.length) 
          # equals
          else return v is a 
      else
        return !!v
  )
```