# jquery input selector with li

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I have list of input textbox with class="txtdate"

and

list of another input textbox with class ="txthrs"

like

```
 <div id="dvlitr"><li id="0"><label class="txtdatewrapper"><input type="text" placeholder="Select Date" class="txtdate hasDatepicker" value="" readonly="" id="txtsDate1"><span class="txtdateicon"></span> </label><input type="text" placeholder="Hrs" class="txthours" value="" id="txtsHrs1"><a title="Add" class="btnadd" href="javascript:void(0)"></a><a title="Delete" id="btndelnewli1" class="btndelete" href="javascript:void(0)"></a><input type="hidden" placeholder="Hrs" value="0" id="iDhdn0"></li><li id="2"><label class="txtdatewrapper"><input type="text" placeholder="Select Date" class="txtdate hasDatepicker" readonly="" id="txtsDate2" value="10/28/2013"><span class="txtdateicon"></span></label> <input type="text" placeholder="Hrs" class="txthours" id="txtsHrs2"><a title="Add" class="btnadd" href="javascript:void(0)"></a><a title="Delete" id="btndelnewli2" class="btndelete" href="javascript:void(0)"></a><input type="hidden" placeholder="Hrs" value="0" id="iDhdn2"></li><li id="3"><label class="txtdatewrapper"><input type="text" placeholder="Select Date" class="txtdate hasDatepicker" readonly="" id="txtsDate3" value="10/30/2013"><span class="txtdateicon"></span></label> <input type="text" placeholder="Hrs" class="txthours" id="txtsHrs3"><a title="Add" class="btnadd" href="javascript:void(0)"></a><a title="Delete" id="btndelnewli3" class="btndelete" href="javascript:void(0)"></a><input type="hidden" placeholder="Hrs" value="0" id="iDhdn3"></li></div>
```

I have to find is there any li with empty date or empty hrs (any one of them)

i tried something like this

```
  var count = $('#dvlitr > li').filter(function() {
            var $txtdate = $(this).children('.txtdate').val();
            var $txthrs = $(this).children('.txthrs').val();
            return (($.trim($txtdate) != '' && $.trim($txthrs) === '') || ($.trim($txtdate) === '' && $.trim($txthrs) != ''))
        }).length;
        alert(count);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mparvez1986/6Wf2f/)

but dint get the desired result

please help

Thanks

Comment: Of course, there is always few methods to obtain same result... I've just try to show you the best, only with jQuery selectors!Now, If you change DOM, or rules, or everithing else, I can't update all the time... But the idea is here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking to your correct HTML markup, you can do this:

```
var count = $('li').filter(function () {
    var $txtdate = $(this).children('.txtdate').val();
    var $txthrs = $(this).children('.txthrs').val();
    return ($.trim($txtdate) === '' && $.trim($txthrs) === '')
}).length;

console.log('count:  ' + count);
```

Demo: [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ab7Tf/)

**UPDATE**

You can do this:

```
var count = $('li').filter(function () {
    var $txtdate = $(this).find('.txtdate').val();
    var $txthrs = $(this).find('.txthrs').val();
    return ($.trim($txtdate) === '' && $.trim($txthrs) === '')
}).length;
```

Comment: A simple selector can do the trick... You complicate the "schmilblick"

Comment: @JoDev: [Are you sure???](http://jsfiddle.net/Ab7Tf/2/) I just removed the `value` attributes from 3 lis but the `count` is still `1`!!!!

Comment: Yes I'm sure... But of course you have to add empty value attribs in your HTML! See [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ab7Tf/3/).Otherwise, a simple `[value]` selector can do it!

Comment: making any entry in input doest not update value attribute, so val is not working, i dont have to populate the inputs with some values

Comment: @MAkela: Try this. make some entry into the inputs and after that click the `button` [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ab7Tf/4/)

Comment: @palaѕн , Yes that is working, in fiddle, even i changed with my condition, that is working, but in my code, it always show 0 :-(

Comment: I have dynamically generated li with textboxes in jquery

Comment: I have used li inside a div

Comment: @MAkela Please post the jQuery code and the full HTML markup that you are using to your question, to get a clear picture of the issue at your end!

Comment: @MAkela: [See this](http://jsfiddle.net/behGe/). I have just modified the class name `txthours` and `children()` to `find()` and kept the logic same....

Comment: what changes u did @palaѕн can i know

Comment: As I said, I have just modified the class name from `txthrs` to `txthours` after looking into your new html markup and `children()` to `find()` in the code...

Comment: i wish i could be able to give you 100 ups for your support apart of 1 ups and marked as answer :-)

Comment: Ok, i was a little wrong... I confess. I've add another solution using plugin, but yours is better I thing. Well done!

Answer (score 1):

> Remove "`:`" before "`input`"... will be better but didn't do the trick!

See [Jquery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) doc for more informations

And you make some mistakes. I thing this one should be correct now :

```
var count = $("li > input.txtdate[value='']+
                   input.txthrs[value='']").length;
```

You want to retrieve only the number of  `li` where both of `txtdate` and `txthrs` are empty?

You can see it in action [in this updated palash fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ab7Tf/1/)

To complete, in the case that empty `value` are in fact when `value` attrib missing, use this one :

```
var count = $("li > input.txtdate:not([value])+
                 input.txthrs:not([value])").length;
```

> To be sure to have value attrib : $('input[type=text']:not([value])).attr('value','');

To retrieve the number of line with almost one of field empty, use this :

```
var count = $.unique($("li").has("input.txtdate[value=],input.txtdate:not([value]),input.txthrs[value=],input.txthrs:not([value])")).length;
```

Update

```
$('input:not([value])').attr('value', '');
//Getting only lines when one of input is empty
$.unique($("li").has("input.txtdate[value=''],input.txthrs[value='']")).length;
//Getting only lines when both inputs are empty
$("li > input.txtdate[value='']+input.txthrs[value='']").length;
```

Trust me, or not...

UPDATE with new DOM input aren't direct child of li

```
$('input:not([value])').attr('value', '');
//Getting only lines when one of input is empty
$.unique($("li").has("input.txtdate[value=''],input.txthrs[value='']")).length;
//Getting only lines when both inputs are empty
$("li input.txtdate[value='']+input.txthrs[value='']").length;
```

I wake up... sorry! So you was right form the beginning, with simple selector, you can't detect a user update of a input! Sorry I was wrong!
I founded this plugin [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060652/jquery-selector-for-input-value) :

```
jQuery.extend(
  jQuery.expr[':'],
  {
    /// check that a field's value property has a particular value
    'field-value': function (el, indx, args) {
      var a, v = $(el).val();
      if ( (a = args[3]) ) {
        switch ( a.charAt(0) ) {
          /// begins with
          case '^':
            return v.substring(0,a.length-1) == a.substring(1,a.length);
          break;
          /// ends with
          case '$':
            return v.substr(v.length-a.length-1,v.length) == 
              a.substring(1,a.length);
          break;
          /// contains
          case '*': return v.indexOf(a.substring(1,a.length)) != -1; break;
          /// equals
          case '=': return v == a.substring(1,a.length); break;
          /// not equals
          case '!': return v != a.substring(1,a.length); break;
          /// equals
          default: return v == a; break;
        }
      }
      else {
        return !!v;
      }
    }
  }
);
```

Wich allow you to make some selecotr like this :

```
$('input:field-value(=)');//for empty

$.unique($("li").has("input.txtdate:field-value(=),input.txthrs:field-value(=)")).length;
```

Comment: i removed value="p" from inputs, all inputs are blank, still showing 1

Comment: Of course, you have to complete others elements, and add value attrib! See this [other fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ab7Tf/3/) where two lines are emty!

Comment: i dont have to populate , i have to enter values in inputs and before saving i have to check

Comment: please look once more , i have modified,actually i was had to check any one textbox of li

Comment: Yes but by default, you may have the `value` attrib in the HTML... So it will work. Otherwise, you can make a little JS for that!

Comment: In the fiddle, it works! I'm completed my answer for the new condition!

Comment: you enter some text in input and then check your fiddle

Comment: It works fine when you put value in HTML... Or in a local file, it works great! Try it on your local network!

Comment: When I click on Save, always return '0' on FF

Comment: @Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

try this. It will retrieve all the inputs and iterate through them.

```
var count = 0;
$('.txtdate, .txthrs').each(function (){ 
    if($(this).val() == '') { //If inspects if the input has an empty value
        //Do something here if the value is empty
        //can add css to change the color or 
        //assign class to it or call method, etc
        count++;
    } 
});
console.log('count:  ' + count);
```