# Select my troublesome input by value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have HTML inputs that are similar to this and go from voucher1 - voucher10:

```
<input maxlength="20" type="text" name="voucher1" id="voucher1" title="Voucher" class="input" value="">
```

There are 10 fields and each one has a unique name and ID. I currently have a function that combines the field values into an array and returns a variable known as ***duplicate*** if the voucher was typed in previously. The goal is to then select the input with the greatest ID (i.e. alphanumerically: voucher10 would be greater than voucher8) and null the field containing this duplicate while displaying a "No duplicates allowed" message.

My duplicate variable function is working perfectly and it returns the duplicate value immediately using `.on(input, function)`. I also have the message displaying whenever I type a duplicate value. The problem I'm having is selecting even one input that matches the duplicate value. If I inspect the inputs in browser, there appears to be no DOM representation of my typed value. I could type "ninja" in 3 or 4 fields and it would never show. Because of that, it seems I can't select the inputs based on value.

I would rather not loop through each voucher and check individually. It seems like jQuery could inspect all inputs that contain "ninja" and then I could use `.val("")` to null it out. This is tricky as the HTML attribute "value" never changes. Any ideas?

Here is my code that finds the duplicate within the array in case anyone needs it however the primary focus is selecting an HTML input whose value attribute never changes. The below function works fine aside from the ".ninja" contains part which was another failed attempt:

```
$(".voucher-input").focusout(function(){
var sorted_goodvouchers = vouchers.sort(); // You can define the comparing function here. 
                             // JS by default uses a crappy string compare.
var results = [];
for (var i = 0; i < vouchers.length - 1; i++) {
    if (sorted_vouchers[i + 1] == sorted_vouchers[i]) {
        results.push(sorted_vouchers[i]);
        // if there are duplicates
        console.log("results");
        console.log(results);
        $(".ninja"):contains(results).val("fail");
        $( "#dupmsg" ).show( "slow" );
    } else {
      $( "#dupmsg" ).hide( "slow" );
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Did you already try a value selector in jquery? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060652/jquery-selector-for-input-value)

Comment: Please post your duplicate detection code. I expect that the solution will be some light modification of it.

Comment: could you not select based on a class name and have a data attribute that keeps track of the rank?

Comment: What you appear to want is for the duplicate detection function to return, not the duplicate value, but the indexes (or ids or a jQuery selection) of any fields that need to be nulled out.

Comment: A value selector will not work as the value never changes for whatever reason. It must be something about the HTML of this form. Traditionally I could do that but it will not work in this case. So if I can't select it by the value attribute, I'm assuming I can't use jQuery by value. I can't use a select based on class name unless it logically means "find input within .class that contains "ninja" as text". Posting duplicate finding code now.

Comment: Do you want a function that filters an existing jQuery set to only those that the value matches a given string? As in this example http://jsfiddle.net/ekp52tqb/ ? Try typing into each field and then type into the Text to match input field

Comment: Juan, that Fiddle is exactly what I am trying to do! Thanks for the link! Simple inputs with no "value" defined, it just matches the string inside of it. Perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I confess I don't really understand your current duplicate detection function. It doesn't correspond with my understanding of the description of what you are trying to achieve. In particular, I don't believe that there is a need to sort anything. Sorting is costly and should be avoided.

If my understanding is correct, then I would get the duplicate-detection function to build and return a jQuery collection containing fields with duplicate values, ignoring those of lowest index in any set of duplicates.

```
$(function($) {
    function findDuplicates($fields) {
        var duplicates = []; //empty array
        $fields.each(function (i, field_i) {
            $fields.each(function (j, field_j) {
                if (j > i && field_i.value != '' && field_i.value === field_j.value) {
                    duplicates.push(field_j);
                }
            });
        });
        return $(duplicates); //return a jQuery collection of duplicate fields
    }

    var $voucherFields = $("input[name^='voucher']").on('focusout', function () {
        var $duplicates = findDuplicates($voucherFields.removeClass('duplicate')).addClass('duplicate');
        if ($duplicates.length) {
            $("#message").text("No duplicates allowed"); //put message in the message field
        }
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fy19Lvwa/)**

Notes:

1. The `j > i` test ensures that :

   - each field is not compared with itself
   - only fields of higher index are included in the returned collection.
2. The `field_i.value != ''` test ensures that

   - empty fields are not compared