# Jquery Selector "Has" Function and conditions

Tags: jquery

I'm learning a bit more about JQuery and the ":has()" Selector Function, though I'm not really sure if I'm using it properly.

Here's my idea:

I want to click a checkbox that is in an Interactive Report's table, and the background of this particular cell, in which the checkbox is in, should change to a different color.

By using it does work, but it changes all the cells that have the "u-tC" class:

```
$('td.u-tC').addClass('changeBackground')
```

I've been trying to use the **:has()** function to specify exactly what cell I want changed, but it's not working, at least not in the way I'm wanting. What differentiates the cell I want to change is that it has a specific "value" attribute inside it, with data in it that I'd like to use to use as a condition for adding the class.

```
<td class=" u-tC" headers="lpb2_id">
     <input type="checkbox" name="f01" value="2_5800">
</td>
```

This is the code I've come up with. It works, but I don't know how to use a condition here. I've looked online and nothing I've tried such as **:contain()** or **:find()** seems to work.

```
$('td.u-tC').has('input').addClass('changeBackground');
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060652/jquery-selector-for-input-value

Comment: Don't post your html code as an image. Post it as code. Or even better as a snippet that fully reproduces your problem.

Comment: I edited it, thanks for thet tip

Comment: @romeuBraga thanks for the link. I tried finding something like that as not to duplicate the question, but none of the links using my title question brought me to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it took me a while, but I figure something out. Through Javascript itself I wasn't able to find a solution, though I got it by using JQuery:

```
$("#"+phone_id_string).addClass('addbackground');
```

The `phone_id_string` parameter was built using the info I needed for the identification of the cell I wanted to change. I decided on creating a string for that because of how far more succinct and cleaner it looked:

```
var phone_id_string = 'phone_id_' + P100_PK.value;
```

That also required that the checkbox I was clicking had the primary key from that table in its id, which looked like this, in the part with the `'f01_' || pk`:

```
apex_item.checkbox (1, pk, decode(column_name,null,null,'CHECKED'), null, null, 'f01_' || pk) as lpb1
```

This creates a dynamically generated id, that made sure that every one of those columns could safely correlate to the row that I wanted. Since I'm using it all inside an interactive report, the row number could change and my function woud fail with that oversight. Now it makes sure that, regardless of filters or pages, it guarantees to find the correct column and row that I wanted to change.

I hope it helps in case someone tries something like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an attribute selector in the `has()` to filter out the correct input

```
$('td.u-tC').has('input[value="2_4900"]').addClass('changeBackground');
```

---

But it sounds like that is the checkbox that triggers the change so you could change the parent cell when the checkbox is changed

Something like

```
$('td.u-tC :checkbox').change(function(){
     if(this.value === "2_4900"){
         $(this).parent().toggleClass('changeBackground', this.checked)
     }
})
```

Comment: Using the first solution, it did theoretically work. I could see on the console that the <td> attribute on the table was being changed, but it remained the same for some reason, using the following:

`$('td.u-tC').has('input[value="2_4900"]').addClass('changeBackground');`

In the end I changed it to a dynamic action as "Add Class", using a Javascript code and using: 

`this.triggeringElement.closest('td')`

Comment: I will still try to use it adding a different class to see if it'll work.

Comment: A demo in jsfiddle.net or other sandbox would help if you still have issues